# OnItemClickListener not triggering in dialog fragment

Tags: android, listview, android-dialogfragment

I have this basic code that puts a listView inside of a DialogFragment, and also a button.

I've put a listener on the button that does `dismiss()` and it works. Then, I've tried putting an `onItemClickListener` on my listView and this one doesn't trigger anything when I click on a list item.

here is the full code :

```
public class ExternalInfoSelectorFragment extends DialogFragment{

    ListView choiceList;
    Button leave;
    private ArrayList<ExternalObjectPoulpe> poulpeGet;

    public static ExternalInfoSelectorFragment newInstance(int title, ArrayList<ExternalObjectPoulpe> liste){
        ExternalInfoSelectorFragment dialog = new ExternalInfoSelectorFragment();
        Bundle args = new Bundle();
        args.putInt("title", title);
        args.putSerializable("liste", liste);
        dialog.setArguments(args);
        return dialog;
    }



    @Override
    public Dialog onCreateDialog(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        View v = getActivity().getLayoutInflater().inflate(R.layout.list_fragment_poulpe_choice, null);
        choiceList = (ListView)v.findViewById(R.id.ListePoulpe);
        poulpeGet = (ArrayList<ExternalObjectPoulpe>) getArguments().getSerializable("liste");
        final externalObjectPoulpeAdapter adapter = new externalObjectPoulpeAdapter(getActivity(), poulpeGet, null);
        choiceList.setAdapter(adapter);
        choiceList.setTextFilterEnabled(true);
        choiceList.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
                ExternalObjectPoulpe eop = (ExternalObjectPoulpe) adapter.getItem(position);
                Toast.makeText(getActivity(), eop.getName() , Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            }
        });


        leave = (Button) v.findViewById(R.id.FermerChoixPoulpe);

        leave.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                dismiss();
            }
        });


        AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(getActivity());
        builder.setTitle(getResources().getString(getArguments().getInt("title"))).setView(v);
        return builder.create();
    }
```

Why is my list listener not triggering anything? Even when I tap on the items of the listView the line doesn't become gray (when it is supposed to be the default behaviour).

The layout :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:orientation="vertical" android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">
    <ListView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/ListePoulpe">
    </ListView>

    <Button
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Fermer"
        android:id="@+id/FermerChoixPoulpe"/>
</LinearLayout>
```

i'm calling it in an activity called CreationSav on a button click like this :

```
ajoutNote.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        ExternalInfoSelectorFragment frag = ExternalInfoSelectorFragment.newInstance(R.string.dialog, getAllNotesTest());
        frag.show(getFragmentManager(), null);
    }
});
```

check below adapter class code :

```
 public class externalObjectPoulpeAdapter extends ArrayAdapter {



    public externalObjectPoulpeAdapter(Context context, List<ExternalObjectPoulpe> list, SavDataWorker base) {
        super(context, 0, list);
    }




    @Override
    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        if (convertView == null) {
            convertView = LayoutInflater.from(getContext()).inflate(R.layout.adapter_list_poulpe_choice, parent, false);
        }

        final ExternalObjectPoulpe eop = (ExternalObjectPoulpe) getItem(position);
        ViewHolderExeternalObjectPoulpe viewHolderExeternalObjectPoulpe = (ViewHolderExeternalObjectPoulpe) convertView.getTag();

        if (viewHolderExeternalObjectPoulpe == null) {
            viewHolderExeternalObjectPoulpe = new ViewHolderExeternalObjectPoulpe();
            viewHolderExeternalObjectPoulpe.titre = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.NomElementPoulpe);
            convertView.setTag(viewHolderExeternalObjectPoulpe);
        }
        viewHolderExeternalObjectPoulpe.titre.setText(eop.getName());
        return convertView;

    }
}
```

The XML of the elements of my ListView :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:orientation="vertical" android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:textSize="20sp"
        android:id="@+id/NomElementPoulpe"
        android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="10dp"/>

</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: Please show your entire code with layouts and activity from which you are opening your dialogfragment if possibble.

Comment: Okay i'm adding it

Comment: Post your xml aswell

Comment: I've added the xml, the adapter of the list and how I called it

Comment: I think your onItemClick is working fine, please try to increase width of your listview and try to click properly on listitem or try to print static text in onItemClick to check if its working or not.

Comment: my god i'm so dumb it was a problem with the width due to one of my conf.... Sorry for the incovenience, thanks for pointing it out...